# React Native change state of dummy data in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

can anyone help me how to do to be able change a stat of **'reserved'** from **true** to **false** in dummy data in **home.js** from **modalDetails.js** ?
https://github.com/FikVlk/Vozickov

Answer (score 0):

This works I believe. I added a button to log your state before and after the change so you can verify that it works. Feel free to remove it, of course.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import ItemList from './itemList';
import Card from '../components/card';
import { globalStyles } from '../Styles/globalStyles';

export default function home({ route, navigation }) {
    const [list, setList] = useState([
        {
            title: 'Kishal',
            body: 'asdasdd',
            reserved: true,
            id: '1',
        },
        {
            title: 'Kishal',
            body: 'asdasdd',
            reserved: false,
            id: '2',
        },
    ]);

    if (route.params) {
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i][id] === route.params[id]) {
                if (list[i].reserved !== route.params.reserved) {
                    setList((prevList) => {
                        const copy = [...prevList];
                        copy[i].reserved = route.params.reserved;
                        return copy;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const reserveCar = () => {
        console.log('yes');
    };

    return (
        <View styles={globalStyles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={list}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Card>
                        <ItemList item={item} navigation={navigation} />
                    </Card>
                )}
            />
            <Button title="LOG STUFF" onPress={() => console.log(list)} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

The easier and better way is to put the state you have in the home component into redux. This is logical because both the modal and your home component need access to the list and need to know which ones are reserved. It also seems likely that more components will need this information in the future as it seems to be one of the main functions of the app you're building.

You can find documentation about react-redux here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate. It's a rather complicated thing to learn, but exceptionally useful after you've learned it.

Stephen Grider has a great video that's the best explanation I've seen. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sjMRS1gJys